# MySQL Pivot Field Names to values in row

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm new to pivoting, so I came here to get some advice on this. I have a table with fields benchmarkname and value. However, another table is populated differently and out of my control: it has each benchmarkname as its own field in the table, with the row value being the value. The layout is below:

### Table 1

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stream    | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pisec     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| iozws     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| iozwb     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| iozrs     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| iozrb     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

### Table 2

```
| BenchmarkName | varbinary(43) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Value       | decimal(14,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

My question is: how do I convert the first table to look like second dynamically? I believe the answer lies in a pivot, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to *unpivot* the first table. UNPIVOTing takes the data from your columns and converts it into rows. MySQL does not have unpivot so you will have to use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
select 'stream' BenchmarkName, stream value
from table1
union all
select 'pisec' BenchmarkName, pisec value
from table1
union all
select 'iozws' BenchmarkName, iozws value
from table1
union all
select 'iozwb' BenchmarkName, iozwb value
from table1
union all
select 'iozrs' BenchmarkName, iozrs value
from table1
union all
select 'iozrb' BenchmarkName, iozrb value
from table1
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I want. One question, though. Is there a way to determine field names dynamically from mysql? For example, doing this to every row in a table or similar. If there isn't that's all right, I'm just looking for automation.

Comment: @jyaworski you would have to see about using dynamic sql to unpivot the data.

Comment: @jyaworski I will try later to come up with a dynamic sql version.